# Optimizing SQL JOIN call

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I have an SQL query that is performing poorly. I've done some research on joins, watched tutorials, ensured that I have the right indexes defined, etc but honestly I am a bit lost as to how to improve performance of this much-called query.

I have the following schema definitions:

```
create_table "training_plans", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "training_plans", ["user_id"], :name => "index_training_plans_on_user_id"

create_table "training_weeks", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "training_plan_id"
  t.date     "start_date"
end

add_index "training_weeks", ["training_plan_id", "start_date"], :name => "index_training_weeks_on_training_plan_id_and_start_date"
add_index "training_weeks", ["training_plan_id"], :name => "index_training_weeks_on_training_plan_id"

create_table "training_efforts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.date     "plandate"
  t.integer  "training_week_id"
end

add_index "training_efforts", ["plandate"], :name => "index_training_efforts_on_plandate"
add_index "training_efforts", ["training_week_id", "plandate"], :name => "index_training_efforts_on_training_week_id_and_plandate"
add_index "training_efforts", ["training_week_id"], :name => "index_training_efforts_on_training_week_id"
```

And then the following call to gather all of the training_efforts associated with a specific training_plan, including all of the related ride objects, where the training_effort plandates are within a target date range, ordering the result by the planate.

```
    tefts = self.training_efforts.includes(:rides).order("plandate ASC").where("plandate >= ? AND plandate <= ?",
                                                      beginning_date,
                                                      end_date)
```

This produces the following query output:

```
TrainingEffort Load (3393.6ms)  SELECT "training_efforts".* FROM "training_efforts" 
  INNER JOIN "training_weeks" ON "training_efforts"."training_week_id" = "training_weeks"."id" 
  WHERE "training_weeks"."training_plan_id" = 104 
  AND (plandate >= '2015-01-05' AND plandate <= '2016-01-03') ORDER BY plandate ASC
```

I believe that I have the right indexes defined. The table is not that large. Yet, this is taking a huge amount of time. As further background, this is on Heroku Postgres. Lastly I'll mention that on my development system, the query is slower than most (3.3ms) but still not anywhere near 1000x slower than the average...

Thanks in advance for any help optimizing this query.

**UPDATE**
Here is the EXPLAIN output for the query (issued on my dev system):

```
explain SELECT "training_efforts".* FROM "training_efforts" INNER JOIN "training_weeks" 
  ON "training_efforts"."training_week_id" = "training_weeks"."id" 
  WHERE "training_weeks"."training_plan_id" = 7 
  AND (plandate >= '2015-01-05' AND plandate <= '2016-01-03') ORDER BY plandate ASC;
                                          QUERY PLAN                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=430.52..432.04 rows=606 width=120)
   Sort Key: training_efforts.plandate
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=15.12..402.51 rows=606 width=120)
         Hash Cond: (training_efforts.training_week_id = training_weeks.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on training_efforts  (cost=0.00..377.25 rows=1089 width=120)
               Filter: ((plandate >= '2015-01-05'::date) AND (plandate <= '2016-01-03'::date))
         ->  Hash  (cost=11.86..11.86 rows=261 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on training_weeks  (cost=0.00..11.86 rows=261 width=4)
                     Filter: (training_plan_id = 7)
```

**UPDATE 2**
Trying a different query to see if my indexes will be used and noting that there are 7x the number of training_efforts when compared to training_weeks (both of which have date columns), I'll try searching on the training_week dates instead of the training_effort dates as follows:

```
explain SELECT "training_efforts".* FROM "training_efforts" INNER JOIN "training_weeks" 
  ON "training_weeks"."id" = "training_efforts"."training_week_id" 
  WHERE "training_weeks"."id" IN (SELECT "training_weeks"."id" FROM "training_weeks" 
  WHERE "training_weeks"."training_plan_id" = 7 AND (start_date >= '2015-01-05' AND start_date <= '2016-01-03')) 
  ORDER BY plandate ASC;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=376.83..378.34 rows=602 width=120)
   Sort Key: training_efforts.plandate
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=14.23..349.04 rows=602 width=120)
         ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=13.95..26.83 rows=86 width=8)
               Hash Cond: (training_weeks.id = training_weeks_1.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on training_weeks  (cost=0.00..10.69 rows=469 width=4)
               ->  Hash  (cost=12.87..12.87 rows=86 width=4)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on training_weeks training_weeks_1  (cost=5.37..12.87 rows=86 width=4)
                           Recheck Cond: ((training_plan_id = 7) AND (start_date >= '2015-01-05'::date) AND (start_date <= '2016-01-03'::date))
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_training_weeks_on_training_plan_id_and_start_date  (cost=0.00..5.35 rows=86 width=0)
                                 Index Cond: ((training_plan_id = 7) AND (start_date >= '2015-01-05'::date) AND (start_date <= '2016-01-03'::date))
         ->  Index Scan using index_training_efforts_on_training_week_id on training_efforts  (cost=0.28..3.68 rows=7 width=120)
               Index Cond: (training_week_id = training_weeks.id)
```

This appears to be slightly better but still I'm not at all confident that this is optimized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many rows are in each table? Did you re-create these table recently or are they old? Have you analyzed the tables recently? It looks like it's doing seq_scans and not using any of your indexes.

I'd issue a

```
vacuum analyze
```

on your entire DB, or at least these two tables. Many times the optimizer will skip indexes if it doesn't have the right statistics on the table.

Comment: I agree with you on the indexes...Why would that be? I'll try another query format and see if it uses the indexes....These three tables have thousands of rows (5-30k). They have been around for several months. Analyzing just now reports that they were auto vacuumed in the past two days.

Comment: Did the execution plan (or speed) change after analyzing? Doing a vacuum analyze is very important as the optimizer makes it's optimizations based on statistics about your data. If it believes that your data is very small, or that you'll be querying a large part of the data, it will skip indexes entirely as they'll likely be inefficient in those cases.

Comment: Thanks joe and @khampson. I'm marking this as the answer because it came closest to fixing the issue. I needed to wait a few days to see the logs and am happy with the results. Basically, I altered the query to 'tefts = TrainingEffort.includes(:rides).order("plandate ASC").joins(:training_week).where(:training_weeks => {:id => self.training_weeks.where("start_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?", beginning_date, end_date)})'. Then, after vacuuming the DB, I upgraded the DB on Heroku from hobby to standard. The combination did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually using the output from the `JOIN`, so I would recommend ditching it altogether and seeing if that improves performance.

I would recommend using a *raw query* (you should be able to call the *ActiveRecord* object's `connection.execute` method with the *SQL* and parameters, substituting `?` for parameters that need to be interpolated by the SQL library (i.e. that are variable) and then passing those parameters as a list as the second arg to the method).

For the raw *SQL*, I'd recommend trying something like the following (substituting placeholders and parameters as needed for any parameters that will vary). I suspect that this will perform quite a bit better.

```
SELECT te.*
FROM training_efforts AS te
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM training_weeks AS tw
              WHERE tw.training_week_id = te.training_week_id
                AND tw.training_plan_id = 7
                AND start_date >= '2015-01-05' AND start_date <= '2016-01-03'
            )
ORDER BY plandate ASC
```

In terms of turning that into an *ActiveRecord* query, I'm not sure that it offers quite that level of control -- it may be best left as a *raw query*.